# Using a file input as stdin for a shell script does not work

Tags: linux, file, shell, ubuntu, input

I have the following script code:

**test.sh**

```
echo "BEGIN"
while read CMD <&1; do
    [ -z "$CMD" ] && continue
    case "$CMD" in
    start)
            echo "get_start"
            ;;
    stop)
            echo "get_stop"
            ;;
    *)
            echo "get_uknown_command"
            ;;
    esac
    echo "END";
done
```

When I run it with:

```
$./test.sh <input.txt
```

I get my script locked

**input.txt**

```
start
stop
sthh
```

Why my script is locked? How I can fix that?

BTW: If I enter the data manually then the script will not lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you need the `<&1` for?
Remove it, and it works.

`while read CMD; do`

```
./test.sh  < input.txt 
BEGIN
get_start
END
get_stop
END
get_uknown_command
END
```

Comment: it works. thank you. Explaination why it does not work with 1?

Comment: I was not careful when I used this code. `<&1` means get from stdout. so my script is expecting input data from stdout and not form stdin. change it with `<&0` will work.